# XAMPP 403 Forbidden

Tags: php, macos, model-view-controller, xampp, frameworks

I am working with php-mvc-master framework on localhost. Changed Document Root to the directory of the framework, this error starts to pop up:

[Image when opening localhost with changed Document Root directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQouW.png)

[Error Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jeDu.png)

Working on Mac OS.

Thanks Beforehand!

Comment: That error message you see in the log file clearly points out what the actual issue appears to be. Have you checked that? Do those two entries in the file system the required permissions? Keep in mind that it is not your personal account that requires access, but the http server process, so the system account that process is executed under.

Comment: Please edit your question and post the errors messages on text instead of images

Answer (score 0):

According to your error, the `.htaccess` file in your directory `~/Documents/php-mvc-master/public/` is not readable. That probably means that either you have a `.htaccess` file with the incorrect permissions, or that the entire directory is unreadable by XAMPP.

In order to remedy this, you could change the permissions of the directory using [`chmod`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chmod), or you could change the owner of the directory to the XAMPP user (normally `www-data`) using [`chown`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chown).

For the latter, you could try something like:

```sh
$ chown -R www-data ~/Documents/php-mvc-master/public/
```

Comment: It appears to give an error: chown: www-data: illegal user name

Comment: Maybe try `daemon` instead of `www-data`?

Comment: One more error ):

chown: /Users/amirguliyev/Documents/php-mvc-master/public//index.php: Operation not permitted
chown: /Users/amirguliyev/Documents/php-mvc-master/public//.htaccess: Operation not permitted
chown: /Users/amirguliyev/Documents/php-mvc-master/public/: Operation not permitted

Comment: Do `sudo chown -R daemon ~/Documents/php-mvc-master/public/`

Comment: Now XAMPP gives an error again.

Comment: @AmirGuliyev Same error?

Comment: Yes, 403 Forbidden again